# PHP PDO SQL Server database issue

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm using SQL Server as a database and PHP PDO to connect, When creating a registration page, I get this error when executing the query

> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\webdev\classes\DB.php on line 36
>   There was a problem creating an account.PHP Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\webdev\classes\DB.php on line 36

Line 36 - `$this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);`

```
<?php
  class DB {
public static $instance = null;

private     $_pdo = null,
            $_query = null,
            $_error = false,
            $_results = null,
            $_count = 0;

private function __construct() {
    try {

        $this->_pdo = new PDO('sqlsrv:server=' . Config::get('sqlsrv/servername') . ';database=' . Config::get('sqlsrv/db'), Config::get('sqlsrv/username'), Config::get('sqlsrv/password'));
    } catch(PDOExeption $e) {
        die($e->getMessage());
    }
}

public static function getInstance() {
    // Already an instance of this? Return, if not, create.
    if(!isset(self::$instance)) {
        self::$instance = new DB();
    }
    return self::$instance;
}

public function query($sql, $params = array()) {

    $this->_error = false;

    if($this->_query = $this->_pdo->prepare($sql)) {
        $x = 1;
        if(count($params)) {
            foreach($params as $param) {
/* Line 36 */       $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
                $x++;
            }
        }

        if($this->_query->execute()) {
            $this->_results = $this->_query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
            $this->_count = $this->_query->rowCount();
        } else {
            $this->_error = true;
        }
    }

    return $this;
}

public function get($table, $where) {
    return $this->action('SELECT *', $table, $where);
}

public function delete($table, $where) {
    return $this->action('DELETE', $table, $where);
}

public function action($action, $table, $where = array()) {
    if(count($where) === 3) {
        $operators = array('=', '>', '<', '>=', '<=');

        $field      = $where[0];
        $operator   = $where[1];
        $value      = $where[2];

        if(in_array($operator, $operators)) {
            $sql = "{$action} FROM {$table} WHERE {$field} {$operator} ?";

            if(!$this->query($sql, array($value))->error()) {
                return $this;
            }

        }

        return false;
    }
}

public function insert($table, $fields = array()) {
    $keys   = array_keys($fields);
    $values = null;
    $x      = 1;

    foreach($fields as $value) {
        $values .= "?";
        if($x < count($fields)) {
            $values .= ', ';
        }
        $x++;
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO {$table} (`" . implode('`, `', $keys) . "`) VALUES ({$values})";

    if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public function update($table, $id, $fields = array()) {
    $set    = null;
    $x      = 1;

    foreach($fields as $name => $value) {
        $set .= "{$name} = ?";
        if($x < count($fields)) {
            $set .= ', ';
        }
        $x++;
    }

    $sql = "UPDATE users SET {$set} WHERE id = {$id}";

    if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

public function results() {
    // Return result object
    return $this->_results;
}

public function first() {
    return $this->_results[0];
}

public function count() {
    // Return count
    return $this->_count;
}

public function error() {
    return $this->_error;
}}
```

Why would this be, I used the same code and had a mysql database and it sent the data to the db no problems, why would it be the case for SQL Server?

Comment: Are you writing your own ORM here? What is all this code for?

Comment: Its for a LogIn & Registration on our site

Comment: You really should be using an existing ORM like [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/) instead of re-inventing the wheel. Writing this code by yourself will mean stumbling through the same problems that have been solved a hundred times before, but without the community code review a well-supported module provides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the `$param` iterations is coming in as an array probably:

```
if(count($params)) {
    foreach($params as $param) {

        if(is_array($param) || is_object($param)){ $param=''; }

        $this->_query->bindValue($x, $param);
        $x++;
    }
}
```

Recommendation for debugging `public function insert()`

```
// add a debug parameter
public function insert($table, $fields = array(), $debug = false) {

    $return = false;

    if(is_array($fields) && count($fields) > 0 && $table != ''){

        // build SQL and debug SQL
        $sql = "INSERT INTO '$table' (";
        $debug_sql = $sql;

        // declare variables
        $sql_fields = '';
        $values = '';
        $debug_values = '';

        foreach($fields as $k=>$v) {

            // encase fields and values in quotes
            $sql_fields.= "'$k',";
            $values.= "?,";
            $debug_values.= "'$v',";
        }

        // remove trailing commas
        $sql_fields = substr($sql_fields, 0, -1);
        $values= substr($values, 0, -1);
        $debug_values= substr($debug_values, 0, -1);

        // finish SQL and debug SQL
        $sql.= "$sql_fields) VALUES ($values)";
        $debug_sql.= "$sql_fields) VALUES ($debug_values)";

        if($debug === true) {
            $return = $debug_sql;
        }
        else {
            if(!$this->query($sql, $fields)->error()) {
                $return = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return $return;
}

// now change the insert call to look like this
die($this->_db->insert('dbo.users', $fields, true)); // <-- notice the true parameter

/**
 * Use the output to directly run the SQL from the MSSQL admin console or whatever they call it and it will provide a much more useful error description
 */
```

Comment: Thanks, i've added that into the code and that passes that section, when it's running this code `public function create($fields = array()) {
  if(!$this->_db->insert('dbo.users', $fields)) {
   throw new Exception('There was a problem creating an account.');
  }
 }` it throws the exception error. the Insert is from the db.php I posted above. why would this be?

Comment: I am going to assume that there is an issue with the SQL that `public function insert(){}` produces. Honestly, your new question make me wonder if you have ever worked with PHP before or SQL in general... Either way this is way off topic now because your original problem is solved.

Comment: What amendments have you made? as it's the same as what I posted originally. Yes it seems the `public function insert() {}` is the problem. My question is based this way as I have never worked with PDO before I have used standard php previously, not using functions or arrays in this way! I learnt this from a tutorial to which all this code was sent to a mysql database. 

This all works perfectly when using that and inserts records as should, I know this as I tested it. My actual database is in MS SQL Server and trying to understand why it works for one and not the other.

Comment: This is the main place I build the sql from `try {
    $user->create(array(
     'username'  => Input::get('username'),
     'password'  => Hash::make(Input::get('password'), $salt),
     'salt'  => $salt,
     'name'   => Input::get('name'),
     'joined' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
     'group'  => 1
    ));

    Session::flash('home', 'You have been registered and can now log in!');
    Redirect::to('index.php');

   }`

Comment: Thank you for the honesty. There are far too many people who plop code on this site and have ZERO clue what they are doing but I am willing to help you because it can be a challenge going from one DBMS to another and you seem knowledgeable. I've jumped between MySQL, MSSQL, DB2, and now Oracle lol

Comment: Thanks, yes I've seen that, but that gets people nowhere, I like to try and find an answer first by reading google etc and trying what people had said about similar questions. My previous experience has been to write the actual sql to select, insert, update etc from posting into the session. this PDO is to build on that knowledge and  program better. Your help would be very useful :-)

Comment: I'm not sure if you've seen my post but I've updated it with a suggestion for the `insert()` function

Comment: I hadn't until now, it just came to me before that there was back tick on instead of single quotes, been looking at that, now trying what you have suggested. Thanks

Comment: Ok, so using your suggestions I have got the Insert statement to be right. This here is what the `die($this->_db->insert('dbo.users', $fields, true));` produces INSERT INTO dbo.users (username, password, salt, name, joined, [group]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) I tried taking the line you suggested out, using what I had already in my create function create, this jumps straight to the exception message I have. Is there a way I can display the whole sql statement to show what would be fields that are in place of the VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) ?

Comment: This is the last edit, please accept my answer because it solved your question.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, I'm working through the code to understand what/how you have done it. When I ran it straight off it gave me an Invalid argument supplied for foreach() on the line `foreach($fields as $k=>$v) {`

Comment: Thanks! That was my bad, check out the edit and see I changed `$fields` into `$sql_fields` for several spots. This is what happens when I post untested code from scratch =)

Comment: No worries, thanks again, input this and all flows through as should. I do need now to look as to why it runs everything as should be doesn't post to the database.

Comment: So I've split things out, I tested the connection on its own and it connects to the database. I then split the sql string into SQL Server and the insert statement inserts the record. I seem to be missing something as to why it doesn't inputting into the database. Why would this be?

Comment: If the SQL produced is flawless and it works when copying it to the MSSQL admin console then you might be having connection or user permission issues. My personal recommendation, look into an ORM like tadman suggested. Good luck

Comment: I'm not giving up, there has to be a reason why it runs but doesn't send data. I've been thinking about the hashing & salt stuff, on a table what field type should salt be, varchar or binary? i ask this as I have been manually testing to see why it doesn't work, sometimes when a sql is produced and I input it manually from the SSMS it wont insert as there is a single quote in the middle of the salt string. Could this be an affecting matter? I've been testing the connection and creating a select statement to return values in the table. This works well, so I know its connecting. Confused! :-)

Comment: Well, debugging PDO statements when binding parameters is a bit of a challenge because the question marks are simply placeholders which get replaced with the contents of the array you send when executing the query. The DBMS, MSSQL in this case, sanitizes and escapes all necessary characters so this would be extremely difficult to recreate in PHP unless you know the algorithm that MSSQL uses. So the `$debug_sql` only serves to show you if your query looks half-way correct. Leave the sanitation to the DBMS and you won't need to worry about SQL injection.

Comment: Of course there is a reason why it's not sending, it's a computer program not a crystal ball. If you learn MSSQL and understand how PHP interacts then it will all make perfect sense and make you regret not using an ORM in the first place because an ORM makes your code portable from one DB to another. I quote tadman `stumbling through the same problems that have been solved a hundred times` <-- I would guess thousands rather than hundreds though.